# Frequency distribution of series in pandas

Tags: pandas

Let's say I have a pandas series:

```
>> t.head()

Timestamp
2014-02-01 05:43:26    35.592899
2014-02-01 06:18:32    33.898003
2014-02-01 10:04:04    33.898003
2014-02-01 10:36:30    35.592899
2014-02-01 12:20:32    40.677601
```

and what I want is a frequency table with bins I can set. This sounds easy but the closest I've come to is via matplotlib

```
In [8]: fd = plt.hist(t, bins=range(20,50))

In [9]: fd
Out[9]: 
(array([ 0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  3,  0,  3,  1,  0,  8,  0, 11, 20,  0, 18,  0,
       19,  6,  0,  2,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]),
 array([20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36,
       37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49]),
 <a list of 29 Patch objects>)
```

but that of course actually plots the histogram. I can find lost of advice on how to plot histograms, but not on how to simply form the frequency distribution; from the above I have the 'bins' as fd[1] (or at least the lower-bounds of them) and the values as fd[0].

I want the frequency distribution on its own in order to later form a Dataframe with the  distributions of a number of series, (all with the same bins). I feel there must be a way to do it without matplotlib?

UPDATE: desired results:

```
{'Station1': 20     0
21     0
22     1
23     0
24     0
25     3
26     0
27     3
28     1
29     0
30     8
31     0
32    11
33    20
34     0
35    18
36     0
37    19
38     6
39     0
40     2
41     0
42     0
43     0
44     0
45     0
46     0
47     0
48     0
dtype: int32}
```

These are wind speeds: once I have similar data from a number of different met stations I want to be able to form a DataFrame with the bins as the index and the columns as the freq. distrs.

VALUE_COUNTS()

I did think about value counts, it gives me this:

```
33.898003    20
37.287800    19
35.592899    18
32.203102    11
30.508202     8
38.982700     6
27.118401     3
25.423500     3
40.677601     2
28.813301     1
22.033701     1
dtype: int64
```

The data itself is clearly A/D converted: the thing is that suppose the next met station has different indices, such as 33.898006 instead of 33.898003, then I'll get a new 'bin' just for that one - I want to guarantee that the bins are the same for each set of data.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are after but have you tried `pd.value_counts`?

Comment: Not sure if this is the best way - t.astype('int').value_counts().sort_index().ix[20:50]

Comment: @user1827356: That's pretty close: the 'binning' is effectively done by `astype(int)`. It'll certainly do fine for now! Thanks.

Comment: ``pd.cut`` is often used for this as well (and you can specify your bins), see here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html#tiling